# Entity framework support for MySql unsigned decimal

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, decimal, unsigned

Entity framework just ignores unsigned decimal column when doing db-first to generate code, since I can't change the data type of the db column to signed, any solution?

Comment: Why can't you change the db column?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, the client doesn't allow me to do it.

Comment: Then you can't really do much afaik. EF never had support for unsigned values, it was addressed [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1489) and was closed as low priority so it's unlikely to be added in the near future

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to "enforce" non-negative values?  Use a `TRIGGER`.

Or, if the values are whole numbers, then use some suitably sized `INT UNSIGNED` in place of `DECIMAL`.

Comment: actually, I tried to force the Entity Framework to treat the unsigned as signed by edit the .edmx file manually, and it works OK.