# Entity Framework Database First Column not showing in model

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 to connect to a MySQL database in my C# project. I added a new column to one of my existing tables and updated my edmx model. However, for some reason, the column was not showing up in the edmx diagram or even in the table's .cs file.

To debug this I tried the following...

1) Delete the entire diagram, clean the project, then update model from database and re-add all the tables.

2) Delete the entire .edmx file, clean the project, and re-add a new Entity Data Model to my project.

3) Start from a fresh C# project.

4) Delete entire .edmx file, drop entire database schema and re-create it, and then re-add a new Entity Data Model.

5) Create new database schema with different name and connect to new schema.

However, all of this led to the same result -- the column is not showing up in my edmx file. I do not understand why it is not being displayed (especially since I tried starting from a fresh new project...). I tried adding columns to other tables and updating the model and those new columns showed up. It is just this one table's model that does not work correctly.

This is the SQL script that creates the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS part_revision;
CREATE TABLE part_revision (
    `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `part_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    `actual_gross` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `upper_specification_limit` DECIMAL(11 , 6 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `lower_specification_limit` DECIMAL(11 , 6 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `control_plan_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `quality_plan_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id` , `part_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`part_id`)
        REFERENCES part (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`control_plan_id`)
        REFERENCES control_plan (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`quality_plan_id`)
        REFERENCES quality_plan (`id`)
);
```

The new columns are upper_specification_limit and lower_specification_limit.

Here is the generated model and .cs file, taken from the new fresh project.

[image: Model in .edmx diagram]

```
namespace CBM1_HMI
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class part_revision
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int part_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int actual_gross { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> control_plan_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> quality_plan_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated_at { get; set; }

        public virtual control_plan control_plan { get; set; }
        public virtual part part { get; set; }
        public virtual quality_plan quality_plan { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE] I tried re-creating the database schema under a different name. However, the result is the same so I am now thinking there is something wrong with my database... but I am not sure what could be going wrong since it is only this table that has a problem. I have another table with columns of the same data type (DECIMAL(11 , 6 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL) and it works fine. I read that old versions of Entity Framework did not show foreign key columns. Even if that was not fixed however, this is a normal column and not a foreign key.

[UPDATE2] Tried adding a new column to my table and updating the model, the new column showed up (as shown below) but the upper_specification_limit and lower_specification_limit columns are still missing. I am now even more lost.

[image: Added Foo column to table]

[UPDATE3] Tried deleting the columns, updating the edmx model, and then re-adding the columns. Same result. Some reason entity framework just hates the names "upper_specification_limit" and "lower_specification_limit" or something....

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I was wrong about having another table with the exact same data type...

Solution is to not use unsigned decimal data type (at least in MySQL).

Changed my data type from an unsigned decimal to regular decimal and now the column shows up in my .edmx file. Maybe there is a bug in Entity Framework 6 with MySQL's unsigned decimal? Regardless, glad that fixed my problem.

[Update] Looks like I am not the first one with this problem ([Entity framework support for MySql unsigned decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566718/entity-framework-support-for-mysql-unsigned-decimal)).